# XMLUnit - Added Tags?

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

When comparing the following two documents with XMLUnit (latest version- 2.3.0)
In this document, the order of elements is irrelevant, however XMLUnit is taking this into account, and since the new element is appended to the beginning of the parent tag, it is detecting multiple changes when only one has occured.

### Original XML (previous):

```
<ACVS>
    <ACV>
        <N>735</N>
        <C>S135</C>
    </ACV>
    <ACV>
        <N>736</N>
        <C>C0S135</C>
    </ACV>
    <ACV>
        <N>7Q4</N>
        <C>C0S135</C>
    </ACV>
</ACVS>
```

### New XML (current):

```
<ACVS>
    <ACV>
        <N>701</N>
        <C>C10S120</C>
    </ACV>
    <ACV>
        <N>735</N>
        <C>S135</C>
    </ACV>
    <ACV>
        <N>736</N>
        <C>C0S135</C>
    </ACV>
    <ACV>
        <N>7Q4</N>
        <C>C0S135</C>
    </ACV>
</ACVS>
```

### Comparison:

```
Diff fileChanges = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromFile(previous))
            .withTest(Input.fromFile(current))
            .ignoreWhitespace()
            .checkForSimilar()
            .build();

fileChanges.getDifferences()
```

I end up with a number of changes as the elements are matched incorrectly:

- ACV[1] - N[1]: Expected '735' but was '701'
- ACV[1] - C[1]: Expected 'S135' but was 'C10S120'
- ACV[2] - N[1]: Expected '736' but was '735'
- etc... then:
- **ACV[4]: New Tag added**

When I am hoping for a single change:

- **ACV[1]: New Tag added**

Is there any way I can achieve this result using XMLUnit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to help XMLUnit understand which `ACV`s belong together by specifying an `ElementSelector` that identifies the pairs. But even then you'll end up with two `Difference`s, apart from "new tag added" there will be a "number of children of `ACVS` is different.

From looking at your examples you seem to think about your `ACV`s as identified by the textual content of the `N` child. This is what you need to tell XMLUnit. The situation is pretty similar to the `tr` example in https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes (replace `tr` with `ACV` and `th` with `N`). You should be able to get the expected result via

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("ACV").thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./N", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .build();
```

or a variation of it.

Comment: This was very useful, thank you! In my question I used a small snippet of the full XML. In the full file there are actually a number of tags which should be identified by a child <N> tag. I was able to create a conditional builder and call the second line (from above) on this for each of these tags.